# Excel 2010: Conditional Format Class Schedule based on Subject name

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Excel 2010, creating a class schedule.  Colour coded per class name.

I have a table, broken in to 10 min amounts.
7 wide, 30 down.

I want to conditionally format all cells that contain the letters ENG in green, all SCI in yellow & so on.

Currently my table colours end up with the top priority cell, rather than end up with a multi-coloured table.

In conditional formatting:
`=$R$12="ENG"`

`=$R$11:$V$20,$R$25:$V$29,$R$34:$V$38 colour = Green`

`=$R$17="SCI"`
`=$R$11:$V$20,$R$25:$V$29,$R$34:$V$38 colour = Purple`

I either get 'green' or 'purple', I don't get a table with both colours in their respective cells.

`R12 = Green`
`R17 = Purple`
`U12 = Cyan (eventually)`  etc etc

I know I'm missing something, I don't know what though.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative references in your conditional formulas:

If the highlighted cell in your currently selected range is `R12`, edit the formula (with mouse and Backspace/Delete buttons, do not press arrow keys when editing the formula) to:

```
=R12="ENG"
```

...
[image: screenshot with relative conditional formulas]

(see also [Excel vocabulary to find solutions faster](https://superuser.com/a/860920/118860) for a little more background)

---

Also you don't have to use a formula for this use case, just choose an option
 `Format only cells that contain` > change `bettween` drop box to `equal to` > write `ENG` to the text box.

Comment: thank you for the answer, that worked.  Is there a way to have an "OR" statement?  eg:  PE or Phys  (PE or Physical Education); HHR or Health; etc?  I've tried used an OR that I found, but it's an array and it's refusing it.  Many thanks :)

Comment: `=OR(R12="PE", R12="Phys")` should work, if you have bigger list, you could use `MATCH` but that can be a bit more complicated to set up